# How to bind facelets to CDI beans?

Tags: jsf, javabeans, cdi, managed-bean

I have a simple xhtml page with:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="customer" value="#{customersTableBackingBean.allCustomers}">
        <p:column headerText="First Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{customer.contactFirstName}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="City">
            <h:outputText value="#{customer.city}" />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

When my CustomersTableBackingBean.java is as follows:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class CustomersTableBackingBean {

    @EJB(name = "#{customersService}")
    CustomersService customersService;

    public List<Customers> getAllCustomers(){
        return customersService.getAllCustomers();
    }

    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello from a managed bean!";
    }

}
```

I see some data fetched from the database, on index.xhtml as expected.

However when I change the **@ManagedBean** annotation to **@Named** and import: **javax.inject.Named** there is no data in index.xhtml.

What is wrong with this structure?

How can I use a CDI bean instead of a JSF ManagedBean?

( I have a beans.xml file which is empty. )

Comment: By the way I also keep the @ResuestScoped annotation and import: import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

Comment: Seems that you haven't learnt the basics yet: stop having business logic in your getter/setters. Refer to [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2090033/1065197)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question:

beans.xml goes to web-inf folder not to meta-inf !

Comment: Also, you would use `@Named` instead of `@ManagedBean` and the `@RequestScoped` annotation must be from package `javax.enterprise.context`.